# Django Rest Framework: Update object in ModelSerializer based on arbitrary data received from ModelViewSet - looking for a better solution

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I have a ModelViewSet defined as below:

```
class PurchaseOrderApproverViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = PurchaseOrderApprover.objects.all()

    @list_route(methods=['POST'])
    def approve_purchase_order(self, request):
        purchase_order = request.data['purchase_order']
        approver = request.data['approver']
        purchase_order_approver = 
        PurchaseOrderApprover.objects.filter(approver=approver, 
        purchase_order=purchase_order).first()
        if purchase_order_approver:
            serializer = PurchaseOrderApproverSerializer()
            serializer.approve(purchase_order_approver)
            content = {'success'}
            return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            raise Http404
```

and the corresponding ModelSerializer is:

```
class PurchaseOrderApproverSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = PurchaseOrderApprover
        exclude = ('purchase_order', )

    @transaction.atomic()
    def approve(self, instance):
        instance.is_approved = True
        purchase_order = instance.purchase_order
        all_approved = True

        for purchase_order_approver in PurchaseOrderApprover.objects.filter(purchase_order=purchase_order):
            if not purchase_order_approver.is_approved:
                all_approved = False

        if all_approved:
            purchase_order.status = APPROVED
            purchase_order.save()
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Assume `request.data` will contain a json payload: `{"purchase_order": 1, "approver": 1}`, based on those two attributes, I can find the corresponding purchase_order_approver, then, I want to update `is_approved` to `True` via the method `approve` defined in `PurchaseOrderApproverSerializer`.

the model is defined as below:

```
class PurchaseOrderApprover(BaseModel):
    purchase_order = models.ForeignKey(PurchaseOrder, related_name='purchase_order_approvers', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    approver = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    is_approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Because the serializer can only receive data that have been defined in the serializer, so, I have to find the object via a filter in the viewset first, then, initiate a serializer to call the function defined in the serializer to update the object. But I am pretty sure DRF provides a better (or simpler) way to do it.

I am looking for something such as customized viewset method or override the update method in serializer to achieve this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, inside your serializer method `approve()`, you can use the Serializer's context, then you have access to the request. Based on that you should get the `request.data`.

Inside your Serializer method:

```
request = self.context.get('request')

# In cases of your data came as a GET params 
print(request.query_params)
# Normal post/patch/put method request data
print(request.data)
```

Comment: awesome, thanks @luan-fonseca, it works, but need to add an extra input in my ModelView
 
    serializer = PurchaseOrderApproverSerializer(context={'request': request})

because i manually created this serializer, so, i have to pass the context manually from viewset to serializer as well.

do you think this is the best way to do it by giving two custom function one in viewset and one in serializer? 

is there any other way to achieve the same thing by either creating a method in viewset or override a method in serializer?

Comment: Hey, i think you should use the `serializer_class` argument on your viewset, see the drf example: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset

But that may broke something, 'cause the Serializer é implemented just to create/update i think.